# UITableView, view gets stuck?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, view

so basically I have a UITableView and when using it to switch between other views some times going back to the main view the view I was just at gets "stuck". The Bar at top switches to the right title and the back button disappears but the Tableview is now covered by the view I was just at. This only happens after about 10 times though of switching, anyhelp? thanks!

Error:

```
CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: *** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x4e33140> was mutated while being enumerated.(
    "<Note: 0x4e0e520>",
    "<Note: 0x4e0d1b0>"
)
```

I should probably add that "Note" is just a NSObject

code for switching:
RootViewController.m

```
//create a string at the index of array where you clicked
    Note *note = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    //Create view controller
    EditView *editView = [[EditView alloc]init];

    //Pass a long object
    [editView setNote:note];


    //Push, release
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:editView animated:YES];
    [editView release];
```

This code seems to be causing some issue, it's basically to resave an object to an array with a added atribute. Its used with EditView.

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    for(Note *i in [Data sharedData].listOfItems){
        if (i == note) {
            i.info = infoField.text;

            [[Data sharedData].listOfItems replaceObjectAtIndex:[[Data sharedData].listOfItems indexOfObject:i] withObject:i];
            NSLog(@"%@",i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it complain about listOfItems or some other array? (you can do NSLog(@"%x", listOfItems) to get the address and compare it to the address in exception. Is it a mutable array? If you push controller without animation does the problem disappear?

Comment: "Mutated while being enumerated" implies some async action is modifying the object.  If you're not running some operation that would do such async modification I'd tend to suspect that you have an object you released too soon -- either the NSArray or one of the Notes it contains.

Comment: So I just turned off animation and got a different error pointing to the code I just added to the bottom of the post. I think at this point it is a memory problem but can't seem to figure out what it is.

Comment: Getting a SIGABRT on this line ` for(Note *i in [Data sharedData].listOfItems){ `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue. It was when I tried to mess up with animation UINavigationController apply to views. And it almost every-time was in popViewController. Check how you popping view controller, and try to avoid custom animation if you doing some.

Comment: Got it. You are mutating your table view dataSource array in '-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated;'. Didn't put my attention on that part of the code. Sometimes it is in time before table view start to draw itself and sometimes not really. Try to move the code from '-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated' to '-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated;' and if that will not help use delegates mechanism to make data changes right before moving across views.(remember also to 'reloadData' in table view to see changes)

Comment: Hm tried changing it to will dissapear, no effect still getting ` *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x4b31520> was mutated while being enumerated.`

Comment: oh as well as *** Call stack at first throw:terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Comment: Then you'll have to declare your main(UITableViewController that I believe working as UITableViewDataSource also)controller as a delegate to your inner controllers with some callback method lets say :
'-(void)updateNote:(Note)note atIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
for(Note *i in [Data sharedData].listOfItems){
        if (i == note) {
            i.info = infoField.text;
            [[Data sharedData].listOfItems replaceObjectAtIndex:[[Data sharedData].listOfItems indexOfObject:i] withObject:i];
            NSLog(@"%@",i);
        }
   }
}'
After calling that method on delegate call popViewController

Comment: I don't mean to be a pain, just trying to learn, but why would this make a difference then when calling this when the view disappears?

Comment: When you are making call to `-(void)popViewController` on navigation controller it's making sequence of calls. Lets say we have to view controllers first and second, then it would be `[second viewWillDisappear];[first viewWillAppear];[animateTransitionORJustPutFirstViewDependsOnAnimatedFlag];[first viewDidAppear];[second viewDidDisappear];` It's kind of pseudocode for simplicity.

Comment: Now, when first(whose kind we say should be `UITableViewController`getting those calls it start to draw itself, asking his dataSource to give him number of sections, number of items per section and so one. If you starting to change array that works as a data source in between tableView trows exception. So all you need to do is to make change or before calling popViewController or after the first view is fully visible.

Comment: ahh so what your saying is the array is being changed in transition causing an error? But wouldn't that be solved using ViewWillDissapear?

Comment: Nope. When inner controller get it's `-(void)viewWillDisappear;` called, main controller just received `-(void)viewWillAppear;` call. I do not know exactly when the table view start redrawing, but I can guess by resulting error, that it happens somewhere in that method and it take more time then it get `-(void)viewDidAppear;` call. Anyway, if you're making changes to data source just before switching controllers you are avoiding that problem at all.

Comment: Yep looks like you were right, added a "Save" button instead of having it save on view switching and I can't seem to replicate the bug. Thanks!